# Python Module 'distutilis_hack'

Tags: python

I was looking through my pip list and cleaning all my third party modules when I came across a module named 'distutils_hack'. I don't remember installing this, is this something I should be concerned about? The version I was using was Python 3.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used by setuptools to replace the stdlib distutils with setuptools' bundled distutils library.

Quoting ncoghlan from [pypa/setuptools#417](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/417#issuecomment-392298401) on why this is necessary:

> While CPython as a whole has many contributors, we *don't* have many folks contributing to `distutils` any more - folks need build tools that let them target currently *deployed* versions of Python, which `setuptools` provides, but `distutils` really doesn't.
>
> So the challenge for [pypa/packaging-problems#127](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/127) is as follows:
>
> - assume that in some future version of Python (3.9? 3.10? 4.0? We dunno yet) `distutils` is no longer in the standard library per se, but is instead bundled the way we bundle `pip` (i.e. by installing it from a wheel at Python installation time).
> - eventually, for *new* Python versions (where `distutils` isn't in the standard library), we'd like the "real" distutils code to live in `setuptools`, and the code you get when you do `import distutils` to just be a backward compatibility shim that aliases the `setuptools` components into the right place
> - however, for *old* Python versions (where `distutils` is still in the standard library), then `setuptools` will still need to do its monkeypatching magic to allow plain distutils projects to emit the installation database metadata and to be built as wheel archives
>
> The scope of the eventual `distutils-compat` shim probably wouldn't need to be the full distutils API, but it wouldn't be the empty set either.
>
> So @jaraco's suggestion sounds like a reasonable starting point to me: give `setuptools` its own pre-patched copy of `distutils` so it can work on a `distutils`-free copy of Python, *without* providing an importable `distutils` facade.
>
> Building a suitable facade (with a `setuptools` dependency) would then be part of removing `distutils` from the standard library.

Here is where you can find the module's source code: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/_distutils_hack/__init__.py